# Why is this loop printing the same value each cycle?

Tags: c, function, loops, duplicates, call

I have the following loop in main()

```
while (count < 5){
            //with 2^15 as the lower limit
                srand(time(NULL));
                ran_num = rand() % (65536 - 32769); //check READ ME Citation A
                ran_num += 32769;
                binary = Integer_to_Binary(ran_num);
                count += Primality_Test(ran_num, binary, sizeof(binary));
            }
```

The `printf` statement is in the `Primality_Test` function...

```
int Primality_Test(unsigned __int128 ran_num, int binary[], int num_bits){
    int result = Modular_Exponentiation(ran_num, binary, num_bits);
    if (result == 1){
        //the number is prime
        printf("[%d] passes the primality test as prime\n", ran_num); //print binary array too
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        //call Charmichael_Test
        result = Charmichael_Test(ran_num);
        //check for errors
        if (result == 1){
            //number is prime
            printf("[%d] is a charmichael number\n", ran_num);
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            //number is not prime
            //printf("This number is not prime");
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

my output is always the same number even though when I debug it, ran_num is being changed

```
[57221] is a charmichael number
[57221] is a charmichael number
[57221] is a charmichael number
[57221] is a charmichael number
[57221] is a charmichael number
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you call `srand()` in the loop. You use `time(NULL)` which gives time in seconds, so probably the same value for each of your 5 loops. And as `srand()` sets the "starting" point of `rand()` sequences, you have the same value.

Extract `srand()` outside the loop.

Note that with a very large value for your loop you will see a change in printed value each second.

Comment: It's true but has to be a very large value if it's a fast cpu.

Comment: Yes indeed. With some chance one could even see a change with 5 loops :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `srand()` inside the loop. You always reset the random seed in each iteration because `time()` has seconds precision and the time between two iterations is hardly close to 1 *s*.

You should call `srand()` just once at the very begining of the program, preferrably in the `main()` function.